# Eloquent Collection query - 'WHERE' clause with $value parameter without invoked accessor

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have used some accessors for Model attributes.

And as my knowledge about Accessor in Laravel, it can use to create a virtual attribute based on another attribute value or modify the return value of the existing attribute.

So I create an Accessor with the public method getStatusAttribute to convert the status from integer to string value. For example, my Model has an attribute named is 'status'. In DB, this column is stored with integers like 0,1,2,...

In this method, the return value is a string based on the current status attribute value.

```
public function getStatusAttribute(int $value): string
{
    $statuses = [
       1 => 'New',
       2 => 'Pending',
       3 => 'Canceled'
    ];
    return $statuses[$value];
}
```

Everything work fined when I retrieve attribute value from the model object entity.

But when I want to retrieve an Eloquent Collection with a specific 'status' attribute value, the $value parameter in the 'where' method expects a string value that is returned from the accessor method, not is an integer value which stored in a database. So the `$value` parameter would be 'New' or 'Pending' or 'Canceled' instead of 1,2,3.

I want to retrieve a collection that contains an Eloquent Model Object so that I won't use an Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB.

I know I still can retrieve the exact collection with the $value parameter as a string, but I was just wondering if we have another way to skip the accessor in the query of Eloquent Collection?

Please see an example below for more detail about what I expect.

For example, some records in the database look like the below, and the model was named 'DemoModel' :

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 |

```
public function getCanceledEntities($entityId)
{
    $canceledEntities = DemoModel::all()->where('status', '=', 3);
    if($canceledEntities->isNotEmpty()) {
       return $canceledEntities;
    }
}
```

Without an accessor, this query will return a collection containing two entities with id [ 2, 4 ].

But with an accessor (as defined in the model), it can't find a matched entity because the WHERE clause expects that the 3rd parameter is 'Canceled' instead of 3.

My alternative method is to use a string 'Canceled' in the 'where' clause. However, I still want to use the value stored in a database for the query, and I think maybe the framework has another way to write an Eloquent Collection query without invoking an accessor.

Any suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: If the column is named `status`, you shouldn't define a `getStatusAttribute()`, as that will override the value `2` from the Database with your String value `'Pending'`. Instead, define something like `getStatusNameAttribute()`, then calling `->status` will return `2`, and `->status_name` will return `'Pending'`.

Comment: Additionally, don't call `DemoModel::all()->where()`. Do `DemoModel::where('status', '=', 3)->get()`. The 1st way is loading **every record into memory, then filtering**. The 2nd way lets your database do the filtering, then simply returns the matched row.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @TimLewis, I understand your approach, we can use a 'status_name' or 'status_label' as a virtual attribute to show a frontend label for the 'status' attribute and keep its raw value.  Maybe this is the only way to avoid the effect of the accessor.